# Electromagnetic radiation diagram

Tags: electromagnetic, waveform

Would I be correct to assume that this diagram isn't really how the field propagates in space?

But it's just an illustration of the changing electric field strength as a function of time?

For example in a dipole antenna the electric field is actually radial.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Would i be correct to assume that this diagram isnt really how the field propagates in space? But its just an illustration of the changing electric field strength as a function of time?

Yes. The strength  (and direction) of the electric field, and also of the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Any electromagnetic wave has to have zero integral on its E and H components, so it cannot have a single lobe, but will be at least a short wavelet-like package. Now consider your image to be that wave package.

If you played a (time-) movie of your figure, you would see the wave package traveling as a whole to the right. This would apply for the "plane wave" approximation.

For a spherical wave it is the same, but the wave amplitude would dilute over time (how fast depends on the dimensions of the space).

The axis along which the E field is drawn is the "polarization axis" of the radiation and it can change at different points in space and even at different points along the same propagation vector, when passing through certain materials.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EE.SE.

> ... its just an illustration of the changing electric field strength as a function of time?

Yes. It's a graph, not a picture.

It's a graph of the electric and magnetic field strengths along the axis of propagation shown in the picture. If this was visible light we would call this a ray. It is not a picture of what a radio wave would look like if the fields were visible.

> the electric field is actually radial

The picture is just showing a single ray, to make it easier to understand. An actual light source or radio antenna will be sending out EMR that is spreading out in space (lots of rays, to be simplistic). But it's considered nice not to hit beginners with expressions in 3D spherical coordinates for electric and magnetic field strength at any point around a source on day 1.

Comment: People have a delusional understanding of what they can understand and what others can understand. The understanding ability among people in very similar. If anything, it becomes an added deterrent to understanding. Since no where does the diagram ever claim the current wave is not the real representation of the field line propagation

Comment: @ThreadBucks As you haven't given a source for your picture we can't see what, if anything, the source claims for the diagram.